# Are the planets we see in Star Wars colonised? Or homeworlds?

Tags: star-wars

Lots of planets seem to have only one or two locations where the action takes place -

- Naboo: Theed
- Tatooine: Mos Espa / Mos Eisley
- Iego: The city where Jaybo lives
- Bespin: Cloud City

Is this the equivalent of aliens always managing to find either New York or London in Earth sci-fi? i.e. It discounts the vast majority of civilised areas in favour of one or two population centres.

Or is it a result of planets being colonised by small settlements, and the resulting populations being fairly central? e.g. The coastal cities of westerners in early Australia.

Comment: Tatooine is specifically called out as a colony. We actually see [the ship that brought the original settlers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dowager_Queen).

Comment: Naboo is confirmed (in canon) to be a colony since you see the [statue heads of the original inhabitants](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Elders_(Naboo)), pre-dating the arrival of the humans.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know either of those things. I thought the statue heads on Naboo were human, didn't realise it was a now-extinct native species. Thanks.